# How to add error bar plots into a parameter table?

Tags: r, data-visualization, spss, stata, sas

I saw a very neat and clear table in this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13421-018-0797-5:[image]

As shown above, the authors added error bars of parameter estimates into a table, which makes the  essentials obvious and straightforward. Suppose I have a similar data shown above, how can I make one for myself? Does any software package out there just do the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a [forest plot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html), you can [download the r package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/index.html). It's about getting the data into the right format required by the plot. We can use a dataset from `metafor`, calculate the odds ratio, and include it together with 95% confidence interval as one of the columns:

```
library(forestplot)
library(broom)

data = metafor::dat.bcg
res = apply(data[,c("tpos","tneg","cpos","cneg")],
1,function(i)tidy(fisher.test(matrix(i,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))) )

res = do.call(rbind,res)[,1:4]

naming = list(
       "study"=paste(data$author,data$year),
        "odds ratio[95% CI]" = paste(round(res$estimate,digits=2),
        "[",
        round(res$conf.low,digits=2),"-",
        round(res$conf.high,digits=2),"]")
          )

forestplot(labeltext = naming,
           mean = log(res$estimate), upper = log(res$conf.high),
           lower = log(res$conf.low))
```

[image]

The example you showed, i think it's putting together quite a few forestplot which might require more effort. You can also check out this book [example](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/generating-a-forest-plot.html)

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to upvote but don't have enough reputation. It precisely solved my problem.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: You have posted what many (perhaps most) people would call a "high-low-close" plot, such as the one offered in Excel.  I believe what makes something a "forest plot" is that this graphic is integrated with the table of estimates and confidence intervals.  See the first line of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_plot) referenced in your first link.

Comment: Good point @whuber, I updated the post, it was a too simplified example.